# Delphi. Заполнить Image по значениям массива.

Tags: массивы, delphi, delphi-7, изображения

Есть 24 компонента Image.
Есть 12 картинок в формате BMP и именами от 1.BMP до 12.BMP.
Есть массив из 24 значений от 1 до 12 включительно.
Нужно сделать так: 
берётся первое значение массива(например это значение 4) и в компонент Image1 загрузить 4.BMP
затем берётся второе значение массива(например, это значение 11) и в Image1 загрузить 11.BMP.

Гугл подсказал, как похожее делать с Edit, я попытался переделать в нужное мне, вышло что-то типо этого. Похоже, что работать это не должно и в теории...

```
for N := 1 to 24 do  begin
J := StrToInt(Timage(FindComponent('Image' + IntToStr(N))).Picture.LoadFromFile(IntToStr(pole[N])+'.BMP'));
//pole - тот самый массив типа integer
end;
```

Какие есть варианты сделать задуманное?

Comment: а почему не

    for N := 1 to 24 do  begin
        Timage(FindComponent('Image'+IntToStr(N))).Picture.LoadFromFile(IntToStr(pole[N])+'.BMP');
        //pole - тот самый массив типа integer
    end;

Зачем получать J?

Правда данный код будет работать, если на форме есть Image  с нужными именами.

Comment: @KoVadim Не откомпилируется

Comment: А у меня компилируется. На что ругается?

Comment: [DCC Error] Unit1.pas(30): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Timage'
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(30): E2066 Missing operator or semicolon
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(33): E2029 ';' expected but '.' found
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(35): E2029 Declaration expected but end of file found

Comment: Timage - по той причине, что на форме нет TImage и делфи не добавила для Вас его. Но если их нет на форме, то либо нужно самостоятельно добавить (и прописать в uses), либо не жаловаться.

Но если мой код не компилируется, то и Ваш код, приведенный ниже, также не скомпилируется.

Три следующих ошибки - в следствии этой.

Конечно, может быть делфи теперь стала резко "чувствительная к регистру" и нужно писать T**I**mage.

Comment: да лежит на форме имедж я тоже изначально подумал на отсутсвие в uses

покажите полный код своего проекта который компилится.

Comment: на форме TButton и TImage.
вышеприведенный код добавил в обработчик нажатия кнопки. Добавил в var определение N и pole.

Странно, не можете с таким простым случаем разобраться.

Comment: да я разобрался но по своему, такой вариант как вы предложили, я сразу попробовал.

хотя перезапустил IDE и ваш вариант скомпилировался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так это будет выглядеть

```
for N := 1 to 24 do  begin
with FindComponent('Image' + IntToStr(n)) as TImage do
begin
Picture.LoadFromFile(IntToStr(pole[N])+'.BMP');
end;
end;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Работает как часы :)
Только, пожалуйста, разъясните, как работает строка
    with FindComponent('Image' + IntToStr(n)) as TImage do

Comment: Изучите, что такое [with](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/faq_delphi_basics/With.php.html). Но если не понимаете, как работает код, используйте мой - он должен быть понятнее.

Comment: а, With добавляет к следующей(а если в операторных скобках, то следующим) строчкам перед ними код, находящийся меж With и do?
Теперь ясно, благодарю за ссылку :)

Comment: @SaheR, не совсем. With говорит, что дальше будет проходить работа с определенным типом объектов

Comment: > With говорит, что дальше будет проходить работа с определенным типом объектов

нет.
With создает "невидимую" ссылку на объект, который ему передан. Теперь, компилятор, когда будет разбирать код внутри (между begin ... end), то  будет пробовать скомпилировать его как поле/метод объекта, указанного в with. Если нет - тогда будет искать другие процедуры/функции/методы.

Одно с красивых использований with, это такой код

    with TObject.Create() do
    try
       // делаем что то
    finally
       free; // освобождаем.
    end;